# Customer Billing System (Charges, Discounts, Payments, Refunds, Adjustments)

Tags: postgresql, query, schema

### General Overview

I am trying to design a relational schema in PostgreSQL to handle billing for course enrollments and other services/fees. The system needs to be able to handle the following:

- Charges (Charging for a Service or Fee)
- Discounts (Discounting a Charge)
- Payments (Paying for one or more Charges)
- Refunds (Refunding a Payment or some other reason)
- Adjustments (Correcting errors)

The relationship between each of these is as follows:

- A Charge can have 0 or many discounts
- A Payment can have 1 or many Charges
- A Refund can have 0 or many Payments

[image: ER Diagram]

### Current Entities and Fields

Currently I have the following fields for each entity:

| Discount | Charge Discount | Charge | Charge Payment | Payment | Refund | Adjustment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | charge_id | id | charge_id | id | id | id |
| name | discount_id | tenant_id | payment_id | tenant_id | tenant_id | tenant_id |
| amount | name | student_user_id |  | student_user_id | student_user_id | student_user_id |
| percentage | amount | date |  | date | date | date |
|  | percentage | memo |  | memo | memo | memo |
|  |  | description |  | description | description | description |
|  |  | private_notes |  | private_notes | private_notes | private_notes |
|  |  | amount |  | amount | amount | amount |
|  |  | voided |  | voided | voided | voided |
|  |  | amount_due |  | method | method |  |
|  |  | deposit |  | check_number |  |  |
|  |  | deposit_due |  |  |  |  |

### System Requirements

I mainly need the ability to:

- Query a customers current account balance (charges-discounts-refunds-adjustments)
- Directly associate a Payment with one or more Charges (for purposes of content access)
- Query the tables and get the relult in the following format sorted by date and keeping a running total:

| Date | Type | Memo | Method | Debit | Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/20/2016 | Charge | Online Access Fee |  | $5.00 |  | $5.00 |
| 05/20/2016 | Charge | Course Enrollment - Classroom Instruction |  | $100.00 |  | $105.00 |
| 05/20/2016 | Charge | Course Enrollment - Field Instruction |  | $260.00 |  | $365.00 |
| 05/20/2016 | Adjustment | Discount |  |  | -$25.00 | $340.00 |
| 05/27/2016 | Payment | Cash Payment | Cash |  | -$5.00 | $335.00 |
| 06/14/2016 | Payment | Check Payment | CK #1602 |  | -$100.00 | $253.00 |
| 06/20/2016 | Payment | Cash Payment | Cash |  | -$260.00 | -$25.00 |
| 06/20/2016 | Refund | Refund - Overpayment | Cash |  | $25.00 | $0.00 |

So my question is, given the requirements is this the best way to structure the database? If so, how can I write a query to return the data in the format above with everything being in different tables? If not what should I change to be able to meet the requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally I'd recommend **not** doing this unless you are 1. well versed in the subject area 2. Have a solid foundation in database design (relational model, transactions, etc) 3. Know how to have your system pass an audit.  Banks spend millions on these things for a reason.  If it's a hobby project, probably better hobbies out there.

Comment: That said, these answers on SO may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465148/13942986 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29713230/13942986

Comment: Refund should not be an entity; it's simply a reversal of a payment. Discount is not an entity either; it's an attribute of a charge.